# Adsense not showing

Tags: php, google-adsense, apache2, cache

This is kind of a strange glitch, but still..? I can’t figure it out. When I go to a question on my database almost every time, the ads don’t show, but when I change the url by adding page.php?parameter=true to the address bar, the ads load. (it doesn’t matter if the parameter is fictional)

Same when change the url from “askmrmushroom.com” to “www.askmrmushroom.com.” Granted my account is basically brand new, but still! I want the ads to show for my visitors right away. Any suggestions from the peanut gallery?

PS: I had a problem with updating pages before. I would change a simple word on the Home Screen (index.php) from the terminal via ssh and when I would refresh that page, I would see no changes. They said it had something to do with opcache.enable=true in my php.ini, but I never figured it out...

Comment: As you indicated, it sounds like a caching problem.

Comment: Are you using a content delivery network (CDN) like cloudflare?

Comment: I don’t know. I’m hosting my site with google cloud.

Comment: Are you using Google's [cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn)

Comment: I just checked and I don’t think I am using cloud cdn...